# Unregister custom element

Tags: javascript, web-component, angular-elements

Is it possible to unregister a custom element that has been created by createCustomElement?

We use Web Components to wrap out vertical features, all 'parts' of the feature are downloaded before the Web Component is added to the DOM.

What we would really like is to completely destroy the component when the feature is no longer active but there it looks like there is no API available.

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: I only know of one way, but it is rather destructive.Reload the browser page! :)

Comment: here is one relevant issue still unresolved in 2022 https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/754

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the Angular level, there doesn't seem to be any "destroy" or "remove" function alongside `createCustomElement` in [`@angular/elements`](https://angular.io/api/elements).

At the DOM level, looking at the [`CustomElementRegistry` interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-api), the interface provided by `customElements`, there is no "undefine" or similar to accompany `define`. (This may be part of why Angular doesn't have a "destroy" or "remove"...)

So I'd say: No, you can't remove it.